# How to install Debian on Acer Chromebook C720?

Tags: debian, system-installation

I did manage to find a set of scripts to install Ubuntu 13.10 onto a Chromebook (see [link](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2013/10/chrubuntu-for-new-chromebooks-now-with.html)).
However, every hour or so, I get a "System program problem detected" error.
This is obviously not very reassuring.

How do I install Debian onto a Chromebook?
I have heard that it is more stable than Ubuntu.

Comment: I think you can do so using Crouton, see this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJ4WcfHFjKg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically have 2 choices if you want to install an alternative OS.

- [chrx](https://chrx.org/)/[ChrUbuntu](http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/) (traditional dual boot)
- [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) (side by side)

**NOTE:** you'll need to enable developer mode, so you'll be forgoing [verified boot](http://www.howtogeek.com/164788/how-a-chromebook-is-locked-down-to-protect-you/). These 2 tutorials should get you started.

- [Acer C720 Chromebook](http://blog.arogan.com/2014/01/acer-c720-chromebook-haswell.html)
- [How to Install Ubuntu Linux on Your Chromebook with Crouton](http://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/)

Answer (score 2):

Enable developer mode and legacy boot (you'll find a lot of tutorials) and then you can install via USB-Stick.
Worked fine for me ( http://blog.mdosch.de/2013/12/04/debian-gnulinux-auf-dem-chromebook-acer-c720-installieren/ - german)
But to get the touchpad working in debian I had to rebuilt the kernel. You can find it there: http://files.mdosch.de/acer-c720-kernel/