# Free linux shells?

Tags: shell, ssh

I have a chromebook (which is crap for trying to run any file) and I want to find a free online Linux Shell that I can use to run some of my programs. Don't need much data, just something that has python3, pip3, and git. Not looking to put down any money because I'm purely a hobbyist when it comes to programming.

Comment: All Linux shells I know (e.g. [zsh](http://zsh.org/) or [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)...) are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) so in theory you could compile them for your computer. Your question is really how to add a shell and a terminal emulator to a chromebook. You might consider installing a genuine [linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) on it.

Comment: If you want to run the shell and programs on a remote Web & Internet server you probably need to rent a [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) and use `ssh`.

Comment: Consider installing [GalliumOS](https://galliumos.org/)

Comment: "I'm not going to put any effort into providing you an answer because I'm a hobbyist." and a very similar question has been answered at least once (**duplicate**): https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/115456/49853

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for recommendations for an external site.

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck! There are plenty of [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution), and all of the [most popular](https://distrowatch.com/dwres.php?resource=major) ones are [free as in beer, free as in freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre), come with a [shell and terminal](https://superuser.com/q/144666) installed, and usually work great with older hardware. Most of them (except Arch Linux and FreeBSD(?)) make it really easy to install software, and most of them (except CentOS and Debian) keep up to date with new versions of software continuously.

As it sounds like you've never installed Linux before I would recommend either Mint or Fedora, as both are easy-to-install desktop distros with (if I recall correctly) not extremely computing intensive desktop environments. Once you're familiar with those you could cut your teeth on Arch Linux or FreeBSD to get a desktop that is completely optimised for your machine.

Comment: There is a problem with your answer: Chromebooks do not boot these standard bootloaders (out of the box) whether it is UEFI, MBR, Uboot or something else. That's why projects such as https://chrx.org/ and https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/mediatek/acer-chromebook-r13 provide instructions for this particular platform.

Comment: @LiveWireBT Thanks, now I know never to buy a Chromebook. You could probably make your comment a complementary answer; I'd upvote it.